# ArcGIS Online Print Widget Error

Tags: arcgis-online, printing, widget, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have a web mapping application built using the Web App Builder function which contains a print widget. I am using the default ESRI print service (ie the URL is blank in My Organisation - Edit Settings - Utility Services - Printing - URL is blank). The feature layers (created in my ArcGIS Online account) are all publicly shared. I get en arror when I go to use the print function to create an image or pdf.
This is the URL to the web mapping application http://missgis.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=1121af9fcf4f47399ebb0873993689ff

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you print from the map viewer app on this same web map?  Can you include a screenshot into your Q of the settings for the print widget from Web AppBuilder? I notice it works fine if I turn off your operational layers, but not entirely sure why its having a problem with those layers. I work over at Esri Australia, might be worth raising a ticket for this so we can remote in and have a look.